# SQL query to print the Even and Odd Id in separate Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns id and name .

```
create table if not exists id_format (idnum int, name character varying);

insert into id_format values (1,'A');
insert into id_format values (3,'B');
insert into id_format values (4,'C');
insert into id_format values (5,'D');
insert into id_format values (6,'E');
insert into id_format values (7,'F');
insert into id_format values (9,'G');
```

Now the Desired output which I am trying to achieve is  shown below

| left_column | right_col |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | A |
| NULL | B |
| C | D |
| E | F |
| NULL | 9 |

What the process is that all the id starts from 0 and we have to display all the even id in left columns including 0 and the odd id in the right columns.

Performing a case query it check each id and then places it accordingly in the left or right columns.Which is not the desired output

```
select case when (idnum % 2) = 0 then name else null end as left_col,
case when  (idnum % 2) <> 0 then name else null end as right_col 
from id_format
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to approach this (without having to wrap your head around `LAG` and `OVER` functions), would be to break the data set into to separate sets and then join them.  You can do that by using CTEs to represent the separate sets

```
with evens as (select idnum, name from id_format where idnum % 2 = 0),
      odds as (select idnum, name from id_format where idnum %2 = 1)
  select e.name,o.name
    from evens e full outer join 
          odds o on e.idnum = o.idnum - 1
order by o.idnum asc;
```

Output:

```
| name | name |
| ---- | ---- |
| null | A    |
| null | B    |
| C    | D    |
| E    | F    |
| null | G    |
```

Bear in mind that this isn't really a robust solution, as it won't show rows where both the left and right columns are `null` (i.e., this query won't be suitable for some kind of time-series or sequential data).

Here's a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aGGn46AzsqHU6KygVXerJs/0)

Comment: . . This is *an* approach, but it is definitely not the *simplest* approach.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is simple aggregation:

```
select max(name) filter (where idnum % 2 = 0),
       max(name) filter (where idnum % 2 = 1)
from id_format
group by floor(idnum / 2)   -- you could also use idnum / 2
order by min(idnum);        -- or floor(idnum / 2)
```

Note:  The `floor()` is not necessary because the column is an integer.  But I'm leaving it in for clarity.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=54dce76944f1da389d8cfec9aad02984) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Would it make more sense to just order by the same grouping expression for purposes of a simpler query plan?

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . Yes, that would make sense for a better query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
with t as (
    select
        idnum / 2 as i,
        array_agg(name order by idnum) as names,
        array_agg(idnum % 2 order by idnum) as pos
    from id_format
    group by 1)
select
    *,
    names[array_position(pos, 0)],
    names[array_position(pos, 1)]
from t order by i;
┌───┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ i │ names │  pos  │ names │ names │
├───┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 0 │ {A}   │ {1}   │ ░░░░  │ A     │
│ 1 │ {B}   │ {1}   │ ░░░░  │ B     │
│ 2 │ {C,D} │ {0,1} │ C     │ D     │
│ 3 │ {E,F} │ {0,1} │ E     │ F     │
│ 4 │ {G}   │ {1}   │ ░░░░  │ G     │
└───┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```